# Slider Pro - Javascript error - Reference Eror

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, slider

I am trying to use slider pro in a project. However, i'm having trouble intiating it.

I went to the console and idicated me that the variable is not defined. 
I'll show you how to initiate page on Git, and how I've done it.

You can see the error at: www.neevasoft.com/docas

Added the css and javascripts at the folder I connected them to.

This is from GitHub

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( '#my-slider' ).sliderPro();
    });
</script>
```

This is mine

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( '#my-slider' ).sliderPro({
        width: '50%',
        height: 500,
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        visibleSize: '100%',
        forceSize: 'fullWidth'
    });
```

The error is this 
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

The Html is the same as GitHub only changed the location of folders

```
     <div class="slider-pro"id="my-slider" >
    <div class="sp-slides">
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
            <a href="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_large.jpg">
                <img class="sp-image" src="src/css/images/blank.gif" 
                    data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_medium.jpg" 
                    data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_large.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <p class="sp-caption">Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have not included jquery.  Use a cdn or download the file

Comment: I've included these three. 
<script src="libs/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="dist/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

Comment: `JQuery.fn.jquery` run this to see the version of jquery used.

Comment: Thank you Sooraj! I've managed using a cdn file. Thanks a lot